# Prevent Certain Types of Queries (Redshift)

Tags: query-performance, redshift

Some IDEs will allow users to "peak" at data by hitting some button in a menu, and under the hood the IDE performs a `select *` without a `where` clause.  This can be a problem because our Redshift cluster includes a table (via Spectrum) which contains a very large number of rows.  Therefore, running `select *` without a `where` clause bogs down the cluster unnecessarily.

One option is to train users not to run queries without `where` clauses on that particular table, but asking users to remember not to hit an innocuous-looking button in their IDE may not work 100% of the time.

Are there other best practices we can explore here?  For example, is there a way to tell Redshift to disallow queries without `where` clauses on particular tables?  (If for some reason the user really wants all rows, they can include `where 1=1` or something.)  Or is there some kind of server-side lint-like plugin, or server-side query regex filter, that would accomplish similar functionality?

Please note that this is not a security-related question.  If a malicious user *wants* to bog down the cluster intentionally, let's assume they will still be able to do so.  Rather, the intent of this functionality would be to do a favor for users who hit the wrong button or type the wrong thing without realizing the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PostgreSQL has a query timeout setting  - Redshift might have something similar, being a descendant of it. You could also look at restricting the no. of records returned by doing a count before launching the query proper...  but this could load the system also - it's a tricky one!

Comment: Hm, OK.  Thanks for your help!